# Determining pr eliminating empty key:value from an object for multiple filtering purposes

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

My app has a feature where users can filter results based on "blood group" and "city", and areas. Results will be retrieved from DB using Axios for Vuejs through "URL" query strings. Example url is: `http://example.com/api/results?blood=a+&city=london`

It should work in a way that when a user select just blood group from select menu: the url would exclude the `city` parameter. But from my current code, I can't get it stripped of, as a result, the database query returns no results on the basis that `city`returns `null` value.

Here's what I have in my Vue component:

```
    <script>
    export default {
    props: ['user'],

      data() {
    return {
        auth_user: this.user,
        results: {},
        blood_groups: "",
        cities: "",
        districts: "",
        areas: "",
        donorUrl: "/api/donors",
        requestedBlood: "",
        requestedCity: "",
        requestedDist: "",
        requestedArea: "",
        params: {}

    };
     },

     created() {
      this.fetchDonors();

      this.fetchCities();
    },

    methods: {
    fetchDonors() {
      let url = "/api/donors";

      axios.get(url).then(response => {
        this.results = response.data.data;
        this.blood_groups = [...new Set(response.data.data.map(x=> x.blood_group))];
      });
    },

    fetchCities() {

        let url = "/api/location_type/cities";

        axios.get(url).then(response => {
            this.cities = response.data.cities
        })
    },

    selected_blood_group(event) {

        this.requestedBlood = event.target.value;

        this.get();
    },

    get_city(event) {

        this.requestedCity = event.target.value;

        this.get();
    },

    get() {

        let request = {
            params: {
                blood: this.requestedBlood,
                city: this.requestedCity,
                dist: this.requestedDist,
                area: this.requestedArea
            }
        }

        axios.get('/api/donors', request).then(response => {
                this.results = response.data.data
            })

        }
    },

     };
   </script>
```

My query is how can I remove or check if any of the following properties contains empty value, so that I do not include them in `axios` params?

```
   let request = {
        params: {
            blood: this.requestedBlood,
            city: this.requestedCity,
            dist: this.requestedDist,
            area: this.requestedArea
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.

Create a new object(called **testParams**) and add that object in params.suppose **requestedCity** is selected(not only but any variable is selected ). Then you can do like below.

```
if(requestedCity.length!=0)
{
   testParams["city"]=requestedCity; // OTHERWISE DON'T ADD IN testParams object
}
```

Finally while making request through axios add testParams in params object like below.

```
axios.get('/yourUrl/',{
    params:{
        testParams //here vue will automatically sets 'testParams':testParams
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following approach:

```
    let request = {
        blood: this.requestedBlood,
        city: this.requestedCity,
        dist: this.requestedDist,
        area: this.requestedArea
    }

    for(let k in request)
        if(!request[k]) delete request[k];

    axios.get('/api/donors', {
        params: request
    }).then(response => {
            this.results = response.data.data
        })
```

Comment: you just only need to check of for city right? Then could you please tell me why you are looping ?